# EE 2.73 Channel Forms and Grid - no documentation

Tags: channel-form, grid

I'm trying to figure out how to add an editable grid field to my channel form - there is very sparse (i.e. none) documentation for this at the moment.

Basically I just need a logged in user to edit the existing grid field and also to add new rows. However, I don't want all fields to be display, so I need to use a custom_fields type of loop rather than just {field:grid_field_name}.

Even using {field:grid_field} in the form doesn't seem to work very well - I get the 'Add Row' button, but clicking it does nothing at all.

Anyone got this working yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Derek is correct. Simply use the `{field:grid_name}` within the `{exp:channel:form}` tag pair. Make sure you also include the channel form css: `<link href="{path=css/_ee_channel_form_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">`

Lastly, if you're loading jQuery already you could run into some issues as the channel:form will load jQuery as well and you may receive errors and general oddities. You may want to add the `include_jquery="no"` parameter in the form tag.

You may also need to move jQuery to the head of your document if you do the above. I was getting errors as the fields were attempting to access jQuery before it was loaded.

Comment: Thanks, bro. This below line is work for me to solve click of add new row button.
`You may also need to move jQuery to the head of your document if you do the above. I was getting errors as the fields were attempting to access jQuery before it was loaded.`

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, `{field:grid_name}` is (as far as I know) the only supported way to use a Grid field in a Channel Form. I do see that the docs make note of Grid fields under the `{custom_fields}` section, but they then show simply using `{display_field}` when you encounter a Grid field within the Custom Fields loop.

The markup and interaction is pretty complex, so I guess they figure it's too difficult to support.

If `{field:grid_name}` is not functioning as expected, make sure you haven't set `include_assets="no"`, and that you've [loaded the Channel Form CSS styles](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/#including-assets) as well.